# How can I parse the nvidia-smi output using in bash and use the parsed result as input of other commands?

Tags: python, bash

This is the output of my `nvidia-smi` command, I want to parse its output and kill all the python processes that runs on GPU. I already know how to kill all python processes with the following script I wrote.

```
kall () {
    pgrep $1 | xargs kill -9
}
```

And now I want to kill all the processes (get the PID number) that using the GPU so I want to parse the nvidia-smi output.

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 367.27                 Driver Version: 367.27                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 1070    Off  | 0000:01:00.0      On |                  N/A |
|  0%   46C    P2    40W / 166W |   4902MiB /  8112MiB |      1%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID  Type  Process name                               Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0       917    G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                             209MiB |
|    0      1683    G   compiz                                         159MiB |
|    0      3780    G   ...UI2016Q2,UsePasswordSeparatedSigninFlow<P   130MiB |
|    0     25962    C   python                                        2199MiB |
|    0     26103    C   python                                        2201MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

filter your command output with `awk`. If 4th field is "G", print PID (3th field)

```
nvidia-smi | awk '$4=="G" {print $3}' | xargs kill -9
```

EDIT: slightly misunderstood what you wanted. If you want to kill python processes that your tool lists do (as you corrected yourself):

```
nvidia-smi | awk '$5=="python" {print $3}' | xargs kill -9
```

Answer (score 7):

You can get the output you want from the `nvidia-smi` utility directly with

```sh
$ nvidia-smi --query-compute-apps=pid --format=csv,noheader
917
1683
3780
25962
26103
```

See the manpage `nvidia-smi --help-query-compute-apps` for more information on query related to applications running on the gpu(s).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the output is as above one can use the following awk script:

```
$ awk '$2$3 ~ /^[0-9]+$/{print $3}' input
917
1683
3780
25962
26103
```

The above assumes only processes will contain digits only in column two and three.